# Explain about downstream and upstream in rxJava

Tags: java, android

I don't really understand the meaning of *downstream* and *upstream* in *Rxjava*.
What does that mean? Is it equivalent to *subscribeOn* and *observableOn*?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

We can divide stream by seeing its position based on an operator.

```
         upstream          downstream
source <--------- operator -----------> consumer/further operators
```

So from top to the operator, we call it upstream.

From operator to the bottom, we call it downstream.

It's not equivalent to `subscribeOn` and `observeOn`. `subscribeOn` and `observeOn` are only operators. However, we can distinguish the behaviour of that two operators by using downstream and upstream concept.

`subscribeOn` is affecting its upstream and downstream. For example, `subcsribeOn` on this code

```
just("Some String")
  .map(str -> str.length())
  .subsribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // change thread
  .map(length -> 2 * length)
  .subscribe(number -> Log.d("", "Number " + number))
```

will make all the stream (up and down) run on computation thread.

On the other hand, `observeOn` only affecting downstream. `observeOn` on this code

```
just("Some String")
  .map(str -> str.length())
  .observeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // change thread
  .map(length -> 2 * length)
  .subscribe(number -> Log.d("", "Number " + number))
```

only make the downstream run on computation thread.

I hope the explanation will help.